# How to generate weights with constraint \sum{x_i} = 1 for more than two assets in a meshgrid fashion?

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy

I would like to generate asset weights for more than two assets in a meshgrid fashion so that the sum is one. For example, I can use [numpy's linespace](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) with two assets, but not sure how to go about it with more than 2 assets:

```
import numpy as np

# get 3 weight configurations for 2 assets, that sum up to one
[np.array([w, 1-w]) for w in np.linspace(0, 1, 3)]
>[array([0., 1.]), 
  array([0.5, 0.5]), 
  array([1., 0.])]

# get 4 weight configurations for 2 assets, that sum up to one
[np.array([w, 1-w]) for w in np.linspace(0, 1, 4)]
>[array([0., 1.]),
  array([0.33333333, 0.66666667]),
  array([0.66666667, 0.33333333]),
  array([1., 0.])]

# get 5 weight configurations for 2 assets, that sum up to one
[np.array([w, 1-w]) for w in np.linspace(0, 1, 5)]
> [array([0., 1.]),
   array([0.25, 0.75]),
   array([0.5, 0.5]),
   array([0.75, 0.25]),
   array([1., 0.])]
```

**UPDATE:** by meshgrid fashion I mean that the weights are not random but follow a mesh grid pattern, for example, for 3 assets these would be possible configurations. Of course, the granularity depends on the number of weight configurations requested in the `num` argument to such function (equivalent to [numpy#linspace](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html)):

```
[1, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 1]
[0.333333, 0.333333, 0.333333]
[0.333333, 0.666666, 0]
[0.666666, 0.333333, 0]
[0, 0.333333, 0.666666]
[0, 0.666666, 0.333333]
[0.333333, 0, 0.666666]
[0.666666, 0, 0.333333]
```

Comment: can you define "equidistant"?

Comment: @Marat thank you for looking into this question :) indeed updating the question.

Comment: It's hard to understand the question, even with the given example. If each triplet represents a point in 3d space, then the given points are not equidistant from any center, nor is their pairwise distant constant.

Comment: @Stef, thank you, indeed you're right equidistant is not the best description, I will change it to meshgrid-like pattern.

Comment: the problem here is that not every number of points will generate a feasible meshgrid pattern placement. For example, in 3d space it's possible only for n(n+1)/2 of points, where n is the number of steps along one of the axes. 10 points in the example are 4*5 / 2

Comment: @Marat thanks again, it doesn't have to be perfect but follow a meshgrid pattern as much as possible. The context is for plotting the efficient frontier of a set of assets. I'd like to specify the number of points or how fine-grained the grid should be and evaluate the optimization in all those points.

Comment: if they follow a meshgrid pattern, than only certain numbers of points are possible. If meshgrid pattern doesn't have to be perfect, it's easier to sample from uniform distribution - that's what I'd actually do in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that fits your examples.

Using integer partitioning!

```py
from sympy.utilities.iterables import partitions
from more_itertools import distinct_permutations
# if you don't want to install more_itertools:
#     set(itertools.permutations( ... ))
#     is equivalent but less efficient than
#     more_itertools.distinct_permutations( ... )
from collections import Counter  # not really needed; just for .elements()

def weights(dim, grid):
    for p in partitions(grid, m=dim):
        p[0] = dim - sum(p.values())
        yield from (distinct_permutations(x / grid for x in Counter(p).elements()))

print( list(weights(2, 2)) )
# [(0.0, 1.0), (1.0, 0.0), (0.5, 0.5)]

print( list(weights(2, 4)) )
# [(0.0, 1.0), (1.0, 0.0), (0.25, 0.75), (0.75, 0.25), (0.5, 0.5)]

print( list(weights(2, 3)) )
# [(0.0, 1.0), (1.0, 0.0), (0.333, 0.667), (0.667, 0.333)]

print( list(weights(3, 2)) )
# [(0.0, 0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0, 0.0), (1.0, 0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.0, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.0)]

for x,y,z in weights(3, 3):
    print('{:0.2f},{:0.2f},{:0.2f}'.format(x,y,z))
# 0.00,0.00,1.00
# 0.00,1.00,0.00
# 1.00,0.00,0.00
# 0.00,0.33,0.67
# 0.00,0.67,0.33
# 0.33,0.00,0.67
# 0.33,0.67,0.00
# 0.67,0.00,0.33
# 0.67,0.33,0.00
# 0.33,0.33,0.33
```

Relevant documentation:

- [Wikipedia on integer partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory));
- [sympy.utilities.iterables.partitions](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/iterables.html#sympy.utilities.iterables.partitions);
- [itertools.permutations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations);
- [more_itertools.distinct_permutations](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.distinct_permutations);
- [collections.Counter.elements](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.elements).

Comment: Indeed, sorry my bad, looking good :) I am still not seeing where the duplicates come from ...

Comment: @SkyWalker Actually they come from the documentation of itertools.permutations: "Elements are treated as unique based on their position, not their value". So permutations([1,1,1]) says "well obviously there are 6 ways to permute 3 elements" instead of "all three elements are the same, so there's only one way to permute them". This can be remedied using either `more_itertools.distinct_permutations` instead, or using `set(permutations())` to delete the duplicates

Comment: Thanks! btw which words you don't understand from the question?

Comment: Ahh sorry just saw, your solution let's me choose the dimension (or number of assets) but not the number of points.

Comment: @SkyWalker I wrote that because of all the confusion from "equidistant". Now it's a lot more clear. Also, your example is very good. I'll remove that statement from the beginning of my answer.

Comment: @SkyWalker: Ah! See! So I did misunderstand something!!

Comment: @SkyWalker Happily this is easily remedied. Notice how `partitions` takes two parameters; I used the same `n` for both. We can use a different value. Hmm.

Comment: @SkyWalker Tadaaaaaa! Now there are two parameters.

Comment: Hahaha very cool! and clever way to go :)

Comment: @Stef Thanks a lot for your code. Unfortunately, I was not able to reproduce your result. For example, when I try print( list(weights(3, 2)) ) I obtain [(0.0, 0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0, 0.0), (1.0, 0.0, 0.0), (0.5, 0.5)] instead of your [(0.0, 0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0, 0.0), (1.0, 0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.0, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.0)]. I am using Python 3.7.6 in jupyter NB. All libraries were preinstalled. Did you run it perhaps on a different version or could you please confirm that you still obtain the same result? Cheers

Comment: @fuji2015 I confirm that I get `[(0.0, 0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0, 0.0), (1.0, 0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.0, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.0)]` for `list(weights(3,2))`. I use python 3.10.2 with sympy 1.9 and more_itertools 8.10 you can check the version with `sympy.__version__` and `more_itertools.__version__`